# Which XML file should I modify & to &amp

Tags: xml, exception, jasper-reports

Below is the exception that happened. I know the fix, but how can I know which XML should I edit?

```
-- Occured 2629 times -----------------------------------------
 FATAL 871  [JRStyledTextParser] Error parsing styled text. 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEntityReference(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.parse(JRStyledTextParser.java:215)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.getStyledText(JRStyledTextParser.java:254)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextElement.getStyledText(JRFillTextElement.java:1078)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextElement.getText(JRFillTextElement.java:1096)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.prepare(JRFillTextField.java:524)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:329)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:419)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:378)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2035)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:760)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportContent(JRVerticalFiller.java:290)
```

Comment: Surely you shouldn't edit any (non-)XML, you should fix the program that created it.

Comment: how can i know where i should edit? Is there any clue in above logs?

Comment: The information you have given us does not indicate which XML file is ill-formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to check which field in your jasper may derived the & sign in output, and apply your fix there. In my case, I face same issue due to my customerName field derived as Law & Partners.

Comment: if it is derived..how can i fix? Can u show me an example ? thanks

Comment: Now i have to attach "replace all" in every fields. Is there any generic way to do this for every fields rather than doing for each feilds in jrxml file. thanks